# graph theory terminology: name for set of non-MCDS vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

In general, the minimum connected dominating set (MCDS) of a graph is not unique.

**Q1:** Is there a conventional name for the set of vertices which are never part of any MCDS?

**Q2:** Has anyone ever encountered mention of this set in the literature?  My search has turned up nothing, but I'm a non-mathematician who's new to graph theory.

Leaves are obviously in this (nameless?) set, but there are others, as well.  Consider, for example, the paw or 3-pan graph, which consists of 4 vertices and 4 edges, and is obtained by joining a leaf to $C_3$.  The MCDS is unique in this case, and it's a single vertex; thus, none of the other three vertices are ever part of a MCDS for this graph, yet only one of them is a leaf vertex.